# Como hago para remplazar el contenido de una etiqueta html desde javascript y comprobar si existe una cadena dentro de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, html5, array, split

Buenas a todos Espero puedan ayudarme. Estoy recomenzando con *javascript* y me he puesto a hacer una practica que no me da resultado, los objetivos son:

**1-** Mostrar bienvenida en un `alert`.

**2-** Usar un `confirm` para preguntar al usuario si desea proceder.

**3-** Pedir su nombre mediante un prompt y almacenarlo en la variable `nombre`.

**4-** Modificar la etiqueta `<h2 id="modificar">` para mostrar el mensaje `"Bienvenido" + nombre` en caso afirmativo(del `confirm`) o `"Adios"` caso negativo (He probado hacerlo con un condicional).

**5-** Pedir mediante un `prompt` que ingrese sus deportes favorito, separados por una coma.

**6-** Mediante el uso del método `split()` transformar el `string` obtenido en el paso anterior a `array`.

**7-** Verificar si dentro del `array` están  los elementos `"basquet"` y `"beisbol"`.

Llevo hecho esto hasta ahora, les agradecería me orienten y me digan en que estoy fallando. Les agradezco de antemano.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="modificar"></h2>

    <!-- <script src="VINCULAR SU JS"></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        alert("Bienvenidos a mi sitio");

        var response = confirm('¿Desea avanzar?');

        if (response == true){
            document.getElementById(modificar) = "Bienvenido";
            var nombre = prompt("Ingrese Su nombre");
            document.getElementById(modificar) = "Bienvenido" + nombre;

            hobbiesescrito = windows.prompt("Ingrese sus deportes favoritos, separados por una coma");
            var arreglo = hobbiesescrito.split(",")
            cons = arreglo.find(basquet, beisbol);
        }
        else {  
            document.getElementById(modificar) = "Adios";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que en caso negativo la etiqueta tenga "Bienvenido" +"adios"? o que muestre el mensaje "adios" con un modal?

Comment: @AnkiJedi Quiero que la etiqueta h2 con el id modificar diga "bienvenido" en caso de que la variable response asignada al confirm del condicional sea verdadero y siga con la ejecución del los demás pasos o adios en caso de que la respuesta sea negativa y finalice la ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Vale vamos por partes.
Los requisitos 1 y 2 se cumplen sin problema, y como `response` tendrá un valor booleano podrías colocar la variable sola en el `if()` teniendo el mismo resultado:

```
if (response){
   //...
} else{
   //...
```

Creo que lo que buscas hacer en esta linea:

```
document.getElementById(modificar) = "Bienvenido";
```

Es modificar el valor dentro de la etiqueta con la `id="modificar"`, pero este es un uso incorrecto del método `getElementById()`, pues, el parámetro que se debe pasar a de ser un `string`, y le estas pasando una variable que en ningún momento fue declarada, ademas que estas igualándola a un `string` lo que te dará un error de asignación. La forma correcta seria:

```
const modificar = document.getElementById('modificar') //asigno el valor a una variable para no tener que repetirlo luego.
```

Arreglando lo anterior el `prompt` que pide el nombre funciona correctamente, de momento el código lleva lo siguiente:

```
alert("Bienvenidos a mi sitio");

var response = confirm('¿Desea avanzar?');

const modificar = document.getElementById('modificar')

if (response) 
{
    modificar.innerHTML="Bienvenido "; //innerHTML es la propiedad que permite alterar el contenido dentro de una etiqueta
    var nombre = prompt("Ingrese Su nombre");
    modificar.innerHTML += nombre; //aquí estoy agregando el contenido de la variable nombre al texto ya agregado (Bienvenido )
    //...
}else{
        
    modificar.innerHTML = "Adios";
}
```

Ahora sobre las siguientes lineas:

```
hobbiesescrito = prompt("Ingrese sus deportes favoritos, separados por una coma");
var arreglo = hobbiesescrito.split(",")
cons = arreglo.find(basquet, beisbol);
```

Si se resolvió todo lo anterior la primera y segunda linea funcionaran con normalidad, pero la tercera no, pues al método `find()` le estas pasando parámetros incorrectos (este toma una función como primer parámetro y un parámetro opcional), si lo que buscas es saber si `"basquet"` y `"beisbol"` se encuentran entre los deportes podrías iterar en la lista de deportes y hacer algo cuando coincidan con los deportes que quieres buscar (en este caso simplemente mostrara un mensaje de consola):

```
hobbiesescrito = prompt("Ingrese sus deportes favoritos, separados por una coma");

var arreglo = hobbiesescrito.split(",")

for (i of arreglo){
    if (i ==='beisbol'){
        console.log('beisbol se encuentra en las preferencias');
    }
    else if (i ==='basquet'){
        console.log('basquet se encuentra en las preferencias');
    }
}
```

**El código javascript final vendría a ser:**

```
alert("Bienvenidos a mi sitio");

var response = confirm('¿Desea avanzar?');

const modificar = document.getElementById('modificar')

if (response) 
{
    modificar.innerHTML="Bienvenido ";
    var nombre = prompt("Ingrese Su nombre");
    modificar.innerHTML += nombre;
    
    hobbiesescrito = prompt("Ingrese sus deportes favoritos, separados por una coma");
    
    var arreglo = hobbiesescrito.split(",");

    for (i of arreglo){
        if (i ==='beisbol'){
            console.log('beisbol se encuentra en las preferencias');
        }
        else if (i ==='basquet'){
            console.log('basquet se encuentra en las preferencias');
        }
    }
}else{
        
    modificar.innerHTML = "Adios";
}
```

Lecturas recomendadas:

[Javascript.info - prompt, alert, confirm](https://javascript.info/alert-prompt-confirm)

[MDN - Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[MDN - Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)